# Black hair material instead of selected material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

To make this quick, when I go in render view, or actually render the scene, the hair particles appear black instead of purple. So I end up with this abomination. I am using Cycles btw.

[image: That looks great, doesn't it?]

Here are the nodes of the material used on the mesh:
[image]

And a proof that I'm not completely stupid. I am using the same material:
[image]

Can someone help me fix this please?

Link to download the .blend: https://drive.google.com/open?id=11a65XueeeWegHhS8QU3Kjq7_wf-Sz9Rs
The model is nsfw, so I only put the head, sorry.

Comment: @Sachichi You forgot to pack your textures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some poking around and it turns out you can't use subsurface shading or normal mapping for hair particles. So I added a new texture called "Shantae_Particle", deleted the *Fresnel* subsurface input, and used tangent mapping instead of normal mapping and it works now.

Also note that the *Principled BSDF* has Fresnel built in so there is usually no need to add it in other ways.

Here is the screenshot and below it is the fixed blend file.

[image]

[image]